# How to set an AuthorizationRequestCustomizer on a DefaultOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, auth0

While trying to get **Spring Security OAuth2 5.4.2** to work with custom scopes and **Auth0** in **authorization code flow**. I stumbled  over a small detail which I have no simple solution for.

To request custom scopes Auth0 requires a user to provide an **`audience` [parameter](https://auth0.com/docs/scopes/sample-use-cases-scopes-and-claims#authenticate-a-user-and-request-standard-claims-and-custom-api-access)**. The redirect URI is created in `org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.DefaultOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver#resolve(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)`.

This process can be amended by using a `AuthorizationRequestCustomizer`, however I do not see any means to inject a customizer and the `DefaultOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver` is not registered as a bean or at least I do not grasp how it is accessible.

Comment: Could you provide more information about the issue?  I know, there aren't any issues to configure Auth0 in Spring Security

Comment: It's quite simple to reproduce: Try to access a custom scope created for an API configured in Auth0, e.g. sth. like "create:projects". Now try to use that scope via authorization code flow. It won't work as Auth0 requires an query parameter `&audience=<<api_name>>` that Spring Security can't provide without having a `AuthorizationRequestCustomizer` patching the request. The issue is not that I'm not able to configure Auth0, but I'm not able to use custom scopes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement custom OAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver and then add it to your spring security configuration

```
.oauth2Login(req->
          req.authorizationEndpoint()
         .authorizationRequestResolver(new YourCustomAuthorizationRequestResolver)
 )
```

Comment: Unluckily the is no easy way to just set the `AuthorizationRequestCustomizer` instead I  had to replace the whole `authorizationRequestResolver` by getting hold of a `ClientRegistrationRepository` and the autorization request base URI. With an parameterized  `DefaultOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver` using `authorizationRequestResolver.setAuthorizationRequestCustomizer(b -> b.additionalParameters(Map.of("audience", "http://localhost:8080/")));`

Answer (score 0):

Below is my scenario:
Spring Boot + Spring Boot Admin + Spring Security.
When the property `spring.boot.admin.context-path` is configured, then the OAuth2 authorization code flow uses a wrong redirect uri, which does not include the `admin.context-path`.

The `org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.DefaultOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver#setAuthorizationRequestCustomizer` is not convenient to update redirect-uri
via the builder, I also plan to rewrite the `DefaultOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver`, since I need to update the redirect uri generation logic. See below:
`String redirectUriStr = expandRedirectUri(request, clientRegistration, redirectUriAction);`

Comment: A better way is to redefine the redirect uri template, which includes the admin.context-path, such as redirect-uri-template: "{baseUrl}${spring.boot.admin.context-path}/login/oauth2/code/", and also add the java configuration loginProcessingUrl(adminServerProperties.path("/login/oauth2/code/"))